# Get Windows ID c++

Tags: c++, registry

I would like read the Windows ID in my program.
So I use RegGetValue in

```
TCHAR value[255];
DWORD BufferSize = 255;
int a=RegGetValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion", "ProductId", RRF_RT_ANY, NULL, (PVOID)&value, &BufferSize);
```

My problem is that in 64 bits OS the function read the folder "SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion" and not "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion"

Unfortunetaly ProductID and DigialProductID is not in the 64 register..
How I could force the read or obtains the Window ID

Best Regards

Comment: Just [RTFM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384129%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: You probably shouldn't be checking the version number this way **unless** its for something like logging or reporting telemetry. If you want to check if you are running a version of windows or greater use the [version api helper functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724832(v=vs.85).aspx). If you want to check if a feature is present there are generally better ways in a feature specific pattern. If you still want to get the version its explained on the version api helper functions docs how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
HKEY key = NULL;
RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion", 0, KEY_QUERY_VALUE | KEY_WOW64_32KEY, &key);
int a = RegGetValue(key, "", "ProductId", RRF_RT_ANY, NULL, (PVOID)&value, &BufferSize);
```

Comment: HKEY key = NULL;
    RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion", 0, KEY_WOW64_32KEY, &key);
  int error=GetLastError();

  int a = RegGetValue(key, "", "ProductId", RRF_RT_ANY, NULL, (PVOID)&value, &BufferSize);

error is 0 but a is 87 and value is empty

Comment: @Boz I've made an edit, I forgot an essential parameter. And error code 87 is `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER`.

Comment: Error 2 :( (ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)
So I will use cmd for write in file and read it.

Comment: @Boz try `KEY_WOW64_64KEY` too.